# Use addons in vaadin 14.4.4

Tags: vaadin7, vaadin10

I am trying to use [ClockCountDown](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/countdownclock) in my springboot project. Below is my code

```
    HorizontalLayout subjects = new HorizontalLayout();

    CountdownClock clock1 = new CountdownClock();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2020, 11, 21, 0, 0, 0);
    clock1.setDate(c.getTime());
    clock1.setFormat("<span style='font: bold 13px Arial; margin: 10px'>"
                    + "Test Left<br />"
                    + " %d days, %h hours, %m minutes and %s seconds</span>");
    subjects.add(clock1);
```

Any suggestions, as when i try to add the component i get an error saying no such method please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Addon's page, it is only supported for Vaadin 6 and 7. It wouldn't work in a v14+ project.